# Refactor Component to FunctionComponent with conditional style (onMouseEnter/Leave)

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

So I'm entering into React world and completed the [tutorial](https://en.reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). We end up with a FunctionComponent :

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

My result is slightly different, I tried to deconstruct props to separate component-specific props from DOM attributes :

```
function Square({value, ...domProps}) {
  return (
    <button
      className="square"
      {...domProps}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

The parent component is :

```
class Board extends React.PureComponent {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value = {this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick = {() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I wanted to do is add a background-color on Square element when I hover it. So I decided to add handlers for mouseEnter and mouseLeave, but I had no idea what to do then.

So I changed my FunctionComponent to a Component :

```
class Square extends React.PureComponent{ 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { value, ...platformProps } = props;
    this.state = {
      isHovered: false,
      platformProps: platformProps,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        {...this.state.platformProps}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({isHovered: true})}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({isHovered: false})}
        style={this.state.isHovered ? { backgroundColor: Color('indigo').lighten(0.5) } : {}}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

This is working but it's ugly and I didn't want to handle conditional styling into Square component. I only wanted Square to be dumb low-level component that I can reuse. What am I missing ?

[Here is the sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/595808890-so-refactor-square-ewe1x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: can you add codesandbox of this one it will be really helpful in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/595808890-so-refactor-square-3m27n

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS [Sandbox added](https://codesandbox.io/s/595808890-so-refactor-square-ewe1x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Okay I will check and update asap

Comment: I think Claudio has posted already a solution, let me know if you need further to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the equivalent function component using `useState` hook.

```
const Square = ({value, ...platformProps}) => {
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState();

  return (
    <button
      className="square"
      {...platformProps}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
      style={
        isHovered
          ? { backgroundColor: Color("indigo").lighten(0.5) }
          : {}
      }
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: it's working. But is it good ? Could I define _dom-properties_ in `Board` component and pass events+style as props ??

Comment: Well, to be honest I would not use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` at all, as this is something you can achieve with `CSS` only.
You should use `onMouseEnter` and/or `onMouseLeave` to handle more complex interaction.
And, regarding the other question, yes, of course you can define event handler in `Board` component.
Actually, that's the only way to modify `Game` component state.
This or using `Context API`. Of course something like `redux` would be okay as well

Comment: Yes the hover thing is just an example. How could I move events handler currently located in` Square` to `Board ` (I mean without 3rd party lib), could I get rid of state management in Square ?  (+ I see you're using arrow-func to declare FunctionComponent, is it a good practice or flavor preference ?)

Comment: If you want to avoid `props drilling` and you don't want to use 3rd party libraries like redux you have to use the aforementioned [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). 
Using context, you can avoid passing props through intermediate elements.
In this case the intermediate element would be `Board`

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, greatly appreciated.